# Hibernate doesn't generate key in bi directional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities that are related by one to one relationship.
I'm using Hibernate as JPA provider.

In EntityA I have the foreign key declaration

```
public class EntityA{
.... //some properties
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_detail_id")
private EntityB entityB;
```

and EntityB looks like

```
public class EntityB{
...//some properties
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityB",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private EntityA entityA;
```

I persist new **entityB** instance via entityManger :

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
EntityA ea = new EntityA ..//constructor with input arguments
EntityB eb = new EntityB ..//constructor with input arguments
eb.setEntityA(ea);
entityManager.persist(eb);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I don't get the id for the foreign key column in entityA, that is the the data base the table for entity a id filled except the foreign key column that points to entityB , But if I persist new instance of EntityA all works fine

Comment: Can you paste the code, that's writing `EntityB`?

Comment: Can you check what sql queries are executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `@OneToOne` mapping in both `EntityA` and `EntityB`. 
You need to set `@OneToOne` Object in both entities.

Try something like this

```
public void saveData() {
    EntityA a = new EntityA(...);
    EntityB b = new EntityB(...);
    a.setEntityB(b);
    b.setEntityA(a);

    entityManager.persist(a);
    ...
}
```

Refer [here](https://www.journaldev.com/2916/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-example-annotation) for more detail